# Problems with function calling in Python

Tags: python, function

The issue I am facing is whenever I enter the correct letter, it does not reflect the update in the list "lettersGuessed" when I call the function that's stored under my "getword" variable.

Please see "hangman" function (last one down).

```
import random
import string

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def loadWords():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    """
    print "Loading word list from file..."
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = string.split(line)
    print "  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded."
    return wordlist

def chooseWord(wordlist):
    """
    wordlist (list): list of words (strings)
    Returns a word from wordlist at random
    """
    return random.choice(wordlist)


# Load the list of words into the variable wordlist
wordlist = loadWords()

def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    t=0
    if lettersGuessed ==[]:
        return False
    for i in lettersGuessed:
        if i in secretWord:
            t+=1
    if t == len(secretWord):
        return True
    else:
        return False



def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''
    guesses =''
    for i in secretWord:
        if i in lettersGuessed:
            guesses+=i
        else:
            guesses+=' _ '

    return guesses



def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    '''
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''

    lets = string.ascii_lowercase
    for letter in lets:
        if letter in lettersGuessed:
            lets = lets.replace(letter, "")

    return lets



def hangman(secretWord):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the secret word to guess.

    '''

    lettersGuessed = []
    mistakesMade=0
    chances =8
    getword=getGuessedWord(secretWord,lettersGuessed)
    available = getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)
    print "Welcome to the game, Hangman!"
    print "The secret word contains"+" "+ str(len(secretWord))+" "+"letters"
    while mistakesMade <=8:
        if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
            print "Congrats! You won!"
            break

        else:

            print "You have " + str(chances) + " " + "guesses left"
            guess = raw_input("Please enter a letter: ").lower()
            if guess in secretWord:
                lettersGuessed.append(guess)
                print "Good guess:" + str(getword)
            elif guess not in secretWord:
                mistakesMade+=1
                chances -=1
                print "Oops! That letter is not in my word" + str(getword)




secretWord = 'listo'
# secretWord = chooseWord(wordlist).lower()
hangman(secretWord)
```

Comment: Are you asking for someone to do your homework?

Comment: you don't ever change your `lettersGuessed` list...

Comment: No. I am stuck, i have completed most of it. I want to know why my getword variable is not printing correctly here:

Comment: @user40720 can you provide the contents of WORDS.txt?

Comment: `chances +-1` on line (about) 122 should be `chances -=1` @user40720

Comment: Also @user40720 your `available` variable is never used

Comment: I have changed it from lettersGuessed+=guess to appending, it still does not "Update" my list when i call the functions stored in getword. No needs to know whats in Words.txt since i am testing my code with a non-random word in "listo"  (Look at the very end of the code).

Comment: Haven't implemented the use of the available variable yet as i want to get my getGuessedWord function called appropriately.

Comment: @user40720 I think my answer should answer your question...if I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were never calling `getGuessedWord(secretWord,lettersGuessed)` again after a correct guess, you only called it once initially and then used the variable (`getword`) which would never get updated. If you change `print "Good guess:" + str(getword)` to `print "Good guess:" + getGuessedWord(secretWord,lettersGuessed)`, then you'll be set. Calling `str()` on the `getGuessedWord`'s return value is not necessary, as it returns a string.

It should look something like:

```
print "You have " + str(chances) + " " + "guesses left"
guess = raw_input("Please enter a letter: ").lower()
if guess in secretWord:
    lettersGuessed.append(guess)
    print "Good guess:" + getGuessedWord(secretWord,lettersGuessed)
else:
    mistakesMade+=1
    chances -= 1
    print "Oops! That letter is not in my word" + getGuessedWord(secretWord,lettersGuessed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def hangman(secretWord):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the secret word to guess.

    Starts up an interactive game of Hangman.

    * At the start of the game, let the user know how many 
      letters the secretWord contains.

    * Ask the user to supply one guess (i.e. letter) per round.

    * The user should receive feedback immediately after each guess 
      about whether their guess appears in the computers word.

    * After each round, you should also display to the user the 
      partially guessed word so far, as well as letters that the 
      user has not yet guessed.

    Follows the other limitations detailed in the problem write-up.
    '''
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE...
    
    print('Welcome to the game, Hangman!')
    print('I am thinking of a word that is ', len(secretWord) , ' letters long.')
    guesses = 8
    lettersGuessed = list()
    availableletter = getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)
    print('-------------')
    while guesses > 0:
        print('You have ', guesses,' guesses left')
        print('Available letters: ', availableletter)
        guess = input("Please guess a letter: ").lower()
        if guess in lettersGuessed:
            print("Oops! You've already guessed that letter: ", getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
        else:
            lettersGuessed.append(guess)
            availableletter = getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)
            if guess in secretWord:
                print('Good guess: ', getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
            else:
                print('Oops! That letter is not in my word: ', getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
                guesses -=1
        print ("------------")
        if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
            print('Congratulations, you won!')
            break
   
    if guesses == 0:
        print('Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was', secretWord)
```